# Java null LinkedList from HashMap

Tags: java, null, linked-list, hashmap

I am having trouble figuring out why a certain `LinkedList` is `null` and hence why I get a `NullPointerException.` Here is the output of my program before it crashes:

```
adjList: {vertex: A, rep: A=[vertex: C, rep: C, 6, vertex: B, rep: B, 13], vertex: F, rep: F=[vertex: D, rep: D, 3, vertex: E, rep: E, 2], vertex: B, rep: B=[vertex: A, rep: A, 13, vertex: C, rep: C, 7, vertex: D, rep: D, 1], vertex: D, rep: D=[vertex: B, rep: B, 1, vertex: C, rep: C, 14, vertex: E, rep: E, 9, vertex: F, rep: F, 3], vertex: C, rep: C=[vertex: A, rep: A, 6, vertex: B, rep: B, 7, vertex: D, rep: D, 14, vertex: E, rep: E, 8], vertex: E, rep: E=[vertex: C, rep: C, 8, vertex: D, rep: D, 9, vertex: F, rep: F, 2]}
ufList: {vertex: A, rep: A=[vertex: A, rep: A], vertex: F, rep: F=[vertex: F, rep: F], vertex: B, rep: B=[vertex: B, rep: B], vertex: D, rep: D=[vertex: D, rep: D], vertex: C, rep: C=[vertex: C, rep: C], vertex: E, rep: E=[vertex: E, rep: E]}
true
v: vertex: A, rep: A
null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

`adjList` is a `HashMap` with the key being a user-defined type `UFnode` and the value being a `LinkedList` of `Pair<UFnode, Integer>.`

The following is my code for `Pair.java:`

```
public class Pair<F, S> 
{
    public F first;
    public S second;

    public Pair(F key, S value)
    {
        this.first = key;
        this.second = value;
    }

    public Pair(Pair<F, S> p)
    {
        this.first = p.first;
        this.second = p.second;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("%s, %s", this.first, this.second);
    }
}
```

The following is my code for `UFnode:`

```
public class UFnode
{
    public String vertex;
    public UFnode rep;

    public UFnode(String vertex)
    {
    this.vertex = vertex;
    this.rep = this;
    }
    public UFnode(String vertex, UFnode rep)
    {
    this.vertex = vertex;
    this.rep = rep;
    }
    public UFnode(UFnode node)
    {
    this.vertex = node.vertex;
    this.rep = node.rep;
    }
    public void setRep(UFnode rep)
    {
    this.rep = rep;
    }
    public String getVertex()
    {
    return this.vertex;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
    return String.format("vertex: %s, rep: %s", this.vertex, this.rep.vertex);
    }
}
```

Here is `main:`

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    bar b = new bar();        //bar will print out adjList and ufList after construction
    b.foo();                  //I get my error here
}
```

Here is the constructor for `bar:`

```
public bar()
{
    adjList = initAdjListDefault();
    ufList = initUfListDefault();

    System.out.printf("adjList: %s\n", adjList.toString());
    System.out.printf("ufList: %s\n", ufList.toString());
}
```

Here are the definitions for `adjList` and `ufList:`

```
public HashMap<UFnode, LinkedList<Pair<UFnode, Integer>>> adjList;
public HashMap<UFnode, LinkedList<UFnode>> ufList;
```

The following is the code segment where my error occurs inside `foo()`:

```
Iterator it = ufList.get(u).iterator();
while(it.hasNext())      //for each vertex in component C
{
    UFnode v = new UFnode((UFnode)it.next());
    if( instanceof UFnode)
        {System.out.println("true");}
    System.out.printf("v: %s\n", v.toString());
    System.out.println(adjList.get(v));             //adjList.get(v) prints `null`
    ...
```

This last statement: `System.out.println(adjList.get(v))` prints `null,` and I don't know why. From the output we can see that `v` is initialized to `vertex: A, rep: A,` also we can see that this is a key in `adjList.`

**Why is the value associated with this key not being returned?**

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You get the NPE because `adjList.get(v)` returns `null` meaning it could not find the `UFnode` that v holds in the list. Why do you create a new UFnode instead of using the one returned by `it.next()`? It would be helpful to see how the Iterator is created.

Comment: I added the `iterator` definition. I see why I got the NPE, however I don't know how `adjList.get(v)` is returning `null.` If you look at the print of `adjList` you will see `v.`

Comment: You must step through this code in an IDE debugger (Eclipse, NetBeans, IntelliJ, etc) to see what the variable values are when you get the NPE.  There's no better way to debug this.

Comment: I printed the value of `adjList` and I get `null.` What else can I do? Does debugging allow me to step through the `HashMap` code?

Comment: At the top you show the contents of adjList and ufList. Your iterator is taking stuff from ufList. Calling `adjList.get(v)` asks the HashMap to find an entry in adjList whose key is the same as `v`. But v is `v: vertex: A, rep: A` and though there's an entry in adjList with vertex: A and rep: A, the "rep: A" in adjList is different than the one in ufList.  The reps contain different linked lists, so they don't match. For them to match the keys must be identical. Perhaps you should use a String as the key in the adjList HashMap and use the `UFnode.getVertex ()` value for that.

Comment: `v = vertex: A, rep: A` this is the first key of `adjList.` No? Am I missing something?